# Delete an entire string from mySql table containing random characters

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, string, replace

I'm trying to delete stings from a DB table that contain random characters ...

The string looks like this:

```
<h1 class="visible-xs">Chocolates</h1>
```

e.g.

```
<h1 class="visible-xs">UNKNOWN</h1>
```

There are thousands of entries like this but the word 'Chocolate' is different in each case.

So basically I want to delete this string from the table field ...

e.g.

```
UPDATE products SET products = REPLACE ( post_content, '**********', '' );
```

where the asterisks donate the string to be deleted.

Please help, I've searched everywhere but I'm a complete noob to this regex stuf!

Comment: Hey Philip, what Regex have you tried so far? A kind of neat way to learn Regex through experimentation is RegExr: https://regexr.com/

Comment: Thanks for the link ... just what I've been needing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I you are running MySQL 8.0, you can use `regexp_replace()`:

```
update posts
set products = regexp_replace(
    post_content, 
    '<h1 class="visible-xs">[^<]+</h1>', 
    '<h1 class="visible-xs"></h1>'
)
```

This assumes that the string to remove does not contain character `'<'`.

Comment: Nice +, but wouldnt the `/h1>` be redundant when checking 1+ characters other than `<`?. @PhilipEvers, you should consider marking the answer by clicking the checkmark (on the left of the answer).

Comment: @JvdV: I see your point. But we don't know what are the possible values in the column, other than the one OP showed (what if we have `'<h1 class="visible-xs">Chocolates</zz1>'`), so I took the conservative root here.

Comment: Thanks for the newcomer advice JvdV. I appreciate the conservative root GMB, moreover I understand the syntax. Look! I'm learning ...